# Golang GORM search conditions

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

Writing a webserver in Golang with gorm & postgres, I got stuck misunderstanding what's exactly going on at the second loop iteration in the following code:

```
...
for _, t := range tasks {
    newDbConn := db.SchoolServerDB.Debug().New()
    err = newDbConn.Where("id = ?", t.DayID).First(&day).Error
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "Error query day with id='%v'", t.DayID)
    }
    ...
}
...
```

First iteration debug:

```
SELECT * FROM "days"  WHERE "days"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ((id = '8')) ORDER BY "days"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Second iteration debug:

```
SELECT * FROM "days"  WHERE "days"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "days"."id" = '8' AND ((id = '38')) ORDER BY "days"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

The key question is: why search conditions are accumulated despite there's a new connection being created each iteration? According to [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.New) search conditions must be cleared every time. I'd like to get the second result like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "days"  WHERE "days"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ((id = '38')) ORDER BY "days"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

Any help appreciated!

**UPD:**
db.SchoolServerDb is just *gorm.DB and Debug() is its method

Table 'days' is made of struct Day:

```
type Day struct {
    gorm.Model
    StudentID uint // parent id
    Date string `sql:"size:255"`
    Tasks []Task // has-many relation
    Lessons []Lesson // has-many relation
}
```

Comment: Can you paste struct for school server db and its debug function? Also what is struct for dayz/

Comment: @ParitoshSingh Please provide more info/

Comment: @MostafaSolati Did you mean @PrimeGrandLol? :)

Comment: @MostafaSolati Updated info. Actually, I guess I misunderstand the Gorm workflow rather than having problems with source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your **Search Condition**. Simply you have provided multiple IDs in your queries from second iteration. One in `Where` and another in `Find`.

Let me write an example like yours

```
ids := []int{1, 2}
var org database.Organization
for _, i := range ids {
    db, _ := connection.NewPGConnection(info)
    db = db.Debug().New()
    db.Where("id = ?", i).Find(&org)
}
```

Here, SQL query in first iteration is as  below:

```
SELECT * FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND ((id = '1'))
```

And in second iteration it will be:

```
SELECT * FROM "organizations"  WHERE "organizations"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "organizations"."id" = '1' AND "organizations"."code" = 'mir' AND ((id = '2'))
```

Why? Because, you have used same variable **day**, to read row result.

First time, Its ok. But second time, your *day* **variable has already an ID in it**. And you have provide another one in `Where`. Thats why, its running query with two ids.

> You are actually providing two `id`, one in `where` clause and another in `Find`.

Change your code to redeclare your variable **day** each time. Like this.

```
ids := []int{1, 2}
for _, i := range ids {
    db, _ := connection.NewPGConnection(info)
    db = db.Debug().New()
    var org database.Organization  // <----- move your variable day here
    db.Where("id = ?", i).Find(&org)
}
```

Each time, new and clean variable will be used. And your problem will be solved.

Thank you. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! This solved the issue!